# Tagging a user in Open Graph API using Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, oauth, oauth-ruby

I have found some really sparse documentation about the options for posting to your feed.

I am trying to post to "/me/feed" and then include a user in that post.  I am trying to re-create the way that you can now do @username in the Facebook Status box, but from the API instead.

Using the Ruby OAuth2 lib I to do the following.

```
OAuth2::AccessToken.new(FBOAuthClient,fb_token).post("/me/feed", :message => status)
```

Which is great, but I want to do something like:

```
OAuth2::AccessToken.new(FBOAuthClient,fb_token).post("/me/feed", :message => status, :to => FUID)
```

Is this possible?

Or can, I post directly with JSON?

Thanks,

Kent

Answer (score 0):

there still seems to be an open bug preventing this. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12074